# Adding columnDefinition property to Hyperjaxb generated @Column attribute

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, hyperjaxb

I am using Hyperjaxb to generate my JPA mappings. Then I use hibernate3-maven-plugin to generate the SQL Script of the database. My problem lies in the fact that I have a type that has a property defined like this:

```
<xsd:element name="priority" type="xsd:boolean"/>
```

The sql script defines the column like this

```
PRIORITY bit,
```

And the JPA entity defines it like this

```
/**
 * Obtient la valeur de la propriété priority.
 * 
 */
@Basic
@Column(name = "PRIORITY")
public boolean isPriority() {
    return priority;
}

/**
 * Définit la valeur de la propriété priority.
 * 
 */
public void setPriority(boolean value) {
    this.priority = value;
}
```

I am using MySql as a backend. The problem raises when my JPA/Hibernate entityManager tries to validate my JPA model against the database. Then I get this error

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in custom.sample_type for column PRIORITY. Found: bit, expected: boolean
```

How can I fix this error? Somewhere I read I could do something like this in java code

```
@Basic
@Column(name = "B", columnDefinition = "BIT", length = 1)
public boolean isB() {
    return b;
}
```

But my JPA java code is autogenerated by Hyperjaxb, so how can I achieve something like that with Hyperjaxb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of [Hyperjaxb](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3).

I'd try customizing your property with:

```
<hj:basic>
  <orm:column column-definition="..."/>
</hj:basic>
```

See the [customizations schema](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/blob/master/ejb/schemas/customizations/src/main/resources/customizations.xsd#L169) and the [ORM schema](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/blob/master/ejb/schemas/persistence/src/main/resources/persistence/orm/orm_1_0.xsd#L508) it uses.

You can also configure per-type customizations if you don't want to customize every single boolean (which you probably don't want):

```
<hj:default-single-property type="xsd:boolean">
    <hj:basic>
        <orm:column column-definition="..."/>
    </hj:basic>
</hj:default-single-property>   

<hj:default-collection-property type="xsd:boolean">
    <hj:element-collection>
        <orm:column column-definition="..."/>
    </hj:element-collection>
</hj:default-collection-property>
```

See [this example](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/blob/master/ejb/tests/cu-one/src/main/resources/bindings.xjb) of a binding file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings
    version="2.1"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:hj="http://hyperjaxb3.jvnet.org/ejb/schemas/customizations"
    xmlns:orm="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
    xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="hj orm annox">

    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3.ejb.tests.pocustomized"/>
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <hj:persistence>
            <hj:default-generated-id name="MySuperId" transient="true">
                <orm:column name="MY_SUPER_ID"/>
            </hj:default-generated-id>
            <hj:default-one-to-many>
                <orm:join-table/>
            </hj:default-one-to-many>
        </hj:persistence>
        <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='one']/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='many-to-many-join-table']">
            <annox:annotate>
                <annox:annotate annox:class="org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade" value="DELETE_ORPHAN"/>
            </annox:annotate>
        </jaxb:bindings>

        <jaxb:bindings node="xs:element[@name='ten']/xs:complexType">
            <hj:basic name="content">
                <orm:column length="1024"/>
            </hj:basic>
        </jaxb:bindings>

    </jaxb:bindings>


</jaxb:bindings>
```

You'll have to place your `hj:default-...-property` elements inside `hj:persistence`. They will then override default mappings.

Comment: Perfect. Just what I needed. Thanks. Great tool, hyperjaxb, btw.